# How can I identify what the issue is with request that returns badrequest?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, bad-request

I'm trying to create a method in C# that is the equivalent of the last sample code provided in https://app.profitshare.ro/files/pdf/api_affiliate.pdf

```
var apiUser = "bogdan";
var apiKey = "111222333444555666777888999";
var phUrl = "http://api.profitshare.ro/affiliate-links/?";
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var now = DateTime.Now;
var time = now.ToString("r");
var queryString = "";
var signatureString = $"POSTaffiliate-links/?{queryString}/{apiUser}{time}";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, phUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("Date", time);
        request.Headers.Add("X-PS-Client", $"{apiUser}");
        request.Headers.Add("X-PS-Accept", "json");
        request.Headers.Add("X-PS-Auth", $"{HMAC_SHA1(signatureString, apiKey)}");
        request.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        request.Content = new StringContent("{'name':'APIEmag','url':'www.emag.ro'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
static string HMAC_SHA1(string signatureString, string secretKey)
    {
        var enc = Encoding.ASCII;
        HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(enc.GetBytes(secretKey));
        hmac.Initialize();

        byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(signatureString);
        return BitConverter.ToString(hmac.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
```

I would expect this code to return a JSON with the url returned by the API, but I get BadRequest every time. I tried different variations of the useragent but the result was the same.

Ended up using RestClient (RestSharp) instead of HttpClient and everything works as it should.

Comment: Do you have access to the server that you are sending the request to?

Comment: No, I don't have access to that.

Comment: In the doc for RestSharp it says it uses get method by default but yours is post, could it be why..

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what exactly is sent and returned in your HTTP requests. You can also manually play with the request in Fiddler - will make the debugging easier. But generally if you don't have access to the server that gives you BadRequest - it is a guessing game and following documentation (if available)